# How to load 3rd party libraries in Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony

I have a small Symfony 3.3 project, and want to use [this](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#installation) library. I have installed it with composer, like it says in README.md, like this:

```
composer require fzaninotto/faker
```

And now I don't know how to include it in my app code. 
It doesn't work with require_once, but I think there should be a better way, to include directly via namespace. So I probably need to register it's namespace somewhere, right?

I'm using Symfony 3.3.

Comment: It is not symphony specific. Have you tried this `$faker = Faker\Factory::create();`? If you want to integrate with symphony look at [this site]($faker = Faker\Factory::create();) at the end

Comment: It worked, thanks. But there has to be "use Faker" before.

Comment: You should also take a look at the [BazingaFakerBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaFakerBundle) that implements the Faker library in the Symfony DIC. So you can see how it has been integrated :-). PS: should be compatible with Symfony 3 but I don't know if it is even for major version like > 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this library is installed OK, it will be in your Vendor directory.

**If it is a Bundle:**

Go to app/AppKernel.php and register it as a Bundle in the `registerBundles` method.
Example:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),        
        new Faker\Bundle\FakerBundle() // Insert this, but make sure the names is correct, this is just an example!
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

**If it is not a Bundle:**

You can just `use` the class you want from it, in the files you need to use it (controllers, services, repositories...).
Example:

```
use Faker\Guesser\Name;
```

Comment: I think you've meant to put backslashes in the second example.